Configuring Agilent datalogger to read the resistance from cable actuated position transducer (string pots) in python
I connected the string pot to the agilent data logger and am trying to read the change in resistance from moving the position of the string.
import numpy as np
import pyvisa as visa 
import time
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import threading
import signal

instrument_address = 'USB0::0x0957::0x0507::MY50000230::0::INSTR' #Data logger address

If I read the displacement directly from the agilent display I am getting the linear change in ohms. If I do it through the python script it changes to voltage and I am just getting a signal that rises and goes back to zero (it looks like it is showing relative displacement).
Does someone know how to get the output in ohms?
def instrument(instrument_address: str, 
     instrument_access_protocol_name: str) -> object() :
     rm = visa.ResourceManager()
     instrument_access_protocol_name = 
            rm.open_resource(instrument_address) 
     instrument_access_protocol_name.write('*RST')     
     instrument_access_protocol_name.write('*CLS')
     instrument_access_protocol_name.write(':DISPlay:STATe %d' % (0)) 
     instrument_access_protocol_name.timeout = 10000 
     return instrument_access_protocol_name

SP_ch = '3001:3002' #channels to read
SP_alfa = '1'
SP_resistance = '1' 
instrument_name = 'my_instrument'
my_instrument = instrument(instrument_address, instrument_name)
#channel list defined

def Scan_list(my_instrument: str, Channel_list: list):
      Channel_list = str(Channel_list)
      Channel_list = 
      Channel_list.replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('','')
      separator = ''
      Scan_Channel_list = separator.join(['@',Channel_list])
      my_instrument.write(':ROUTe:SCAN (%s)' % (Scan_Channel_list))
      print('\n\nSetting up automated scan')
      print(':ROUTe:SCAN (%s)' % (Scan_Channel_list))
      my_instrument.query_ascii_values('READ?')

class SP:
    def __init__(self, instrument: str, SP_alfa: str, SP_resistance: 
    str, SP_ch: str):
        self.instrument = instrument
        self.SP_alfa = SP_alfa
        self.SP_ch =''
        self.SP_ch = self.SP_ch.join(['@', SP_ch])
        self.SP_resistance = SP_resistance
        self.configureSP()
        self.senseSP()

    def configureSP(self):
        self.instrument.write('CONF:RES %s,%s' % (self.SP_ch, self.SP_resistance))
        print('\nString Pot configuration')
        print('CONF:RES %s,%s' % (self.SP_ch, self.SP_resistance))

    def senseSP(self):
        self.instrument.write(':SENSe:RESistance:OCOMpensated %d,%s' % (1, self.SP_ch))
        self.instrument.write(':SENSe:RESistance:RANGe %G,%s' % (10000.0, self.SP_ch))
        self.instrument.write(':SENSe:RESistance:RESolution %s,%s' % ('DEFault', self.SP_ch))
        self.instrument.write(':SENSe:RESistance:ZERO:AUTO %s,%s' % ('ON', self.SP_ch))


are you asking for help with the arithmetic? -- your code makes no sense. if instrument is a str, then you can't call a write() method on it. [mre] required. [tour], [ask].

Hello @ChristophRackwitz, there is a function for the instrument that I missed placing in. Question edited now. Thanks for your help

I am not asking for help with arithmetic, but there is a mistake somewhere in the code that does not allow us to read the ohms but everything gets converted to voltages (and the conversion is not straightforward)

you are using some kind of library. why don't you disclose the name of the library? [mre] still required. your code doesn't run without imports. -- I noticed some undefined namespace visa in your code and googled that... you must state such things.

Hey @ChristophRackwitz, added now. Sorry about the back and forth,  but the code involves 4 different equipment types, with logging, saving, plotting parts so I am trying to present it in the clearest way possible.
